# Tuples vs ViewModel in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new to MVC and I have to create a dashboard page in my applications which has 4 different zones having data related to different models. And i have to make my view strongly typed view. Though I accomplished the task using Tuple in my view.

```
@model Tuple<ModelFirst, ModelSecond, ModelThird, ModelFourth>
```

The question is which is a better way using Tuple or creating a ViewModel having only the desired properties. I have to keep in mind both the performance and number of Lines of codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually view models have metadata associated with them which among other allows you to perform validation and integrates with editor/display templates. Tuples don't seem appropriate. Another disadvantage is that they express less clearly the purpose of each property in the view model (`Model.Item1.x, Model.Item2.x`, ..., no-one else than the original developer can make any sense of this, and if he is like me after few days even he won't be able to make sense).

quotation from @Darin Dimitrov

Comment: @tim_barber_7BB this is `Darin`'s answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188360/replacing-viewmodels-with-tuples